# Find all functions satisfying $(1+y)\,f(x) - (1+x)\,f(y) = y \, f(x/y) - x \, f(y/x)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, contest-math

Find all functions which satisfy:

$$(1+y)\,f(x) - (1+x)\,f(y) = y \, f(x/y) - x \, f(y/x)$$ for all real, $x,y \ne 0$ and which takes the values $f(1) = 32$ and $f(-1) = -4$

I am not sure, which variable to replace for $f(1) = 32$ for example?

Answer (score 0):

in this question $x$ and $y$ play kind of symmetric role, so it doesn't really matter whom to replace.

Place the values of $f(1)$ and $x=1$. Get an equation. Then Put $f(-1)$ and $x=-1$.
Get another equation.

Solving both will cancel the $f(1/y)$ term and you will get an expression for $f(y)$.

I didn't type in all the calculations as they are too long.
Above idea shall take you through.